# How to change jcarousel to vertical in specific screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been circling around the net trying to figure out how to manipulate and change JCarousel scrolling from horizontal to vertical depending on screen size. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Given the code:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
      vertical: true
    });
  });
</script>`

Comment: Please see this link https://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/eNZrQW

Comment: use such tricks like $(window).resize(function(){...}); or $(window).width();

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have this script - 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
      vertical: true
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: @SergiuCostas, could you kindly give me an example how to do this, based on my script? I need to change the scrolling to vertical when the screen reaches (max-width: 1024px). Thanks.

Comment: You can use `'jcarousel:create jcarousel:reload'`. Have a look at https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/cookbook/responsive-carousel.html

Comment: @kiran Dash. Sorry but I just couldn't get it to work. I'm always using JQuery plugins to make my websites cooler but I'm new to javascript.